# Iterating over seq and using \str_case with content of seq does not work

Tags: expl3

I try to give multiple arguments to a function using a comma seperated list (`clist`). This seems to work and I can also iterate over the elements by using a `seq`. However, using the elements of the `seq` as parameters to another function and then using `\str_case` does not seem to work.

Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\HPsatz}[1]{
    #1:~
    \str_case:nn { #1 } {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third~sentence. }             
    }
}

\int_new:N \l__ghs_test_int
\int_new:N \l__ghs_tmpa_int
\seq_new:N \l__ghs_seq_numbers
\newcommand {\GHStext}[1]
{
    % generate seq from clist argument 1
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ghs_seq_numbers { #1 }
    
    % set number of elements in seq
    \int_set:Nn \l__ghs_test_int { \seq_count:N \l__ghs_seq_numbers }
    
    % reset loop counter to 1
    \int_set:Nn \l__ghs_tmpa_int { 1 }
    
    % int_do_while of seq for each element
    \int_do_while:nn { \l__ghs_tmpa_int <= \l__ghs_test_int }
    {
        % print sentence from \HPsatz
        \HPsatz{\seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_seq_numbers { \l__ghs_tmpa_int }}

%       \seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_seq_numbers { \l__ghs_tmpa_int }

        % increment loop counter
        \int_incr:N \l__ghs_tmpa_int
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    Sentences (clist):

    \GHStext{H123, H125}
    
    Sentences (manual):

    \HPsatz{H123}
    \HPsatz{H125}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: this exact issue came up with another user this morning `\str_case:nn ` compares detokenized strings so you are comparing `\seq_item:Nn \l__ghs_seq_numbers { \l__ghs_tmpa_int }` and `H123 ` which are not the same declare an `:en` variant to expand `#1` first

Comment: perhaps you need it in your real application but you don't need the seq or counting the list here you could simply have mapped `\HPsatz`  over the supplied clist which would also have fixed the expansion issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: declare and `:en` variant of what? Of `#1`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That sounds easier but what do you mean with to map over the supplied clist? Can I directly iterate over the clist? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
    \exp_args:Ne \str_case:nn { #1 } {
```

Or declare a `\str_case:en`  variant (which would do the same thing) so that `#1` is expanded before the string comparison.

But simpler would be to map over the clist directly avoiding all the counting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\HPsatz}[1]{
    #1:~
    \exp_args:Ne \str_case:nn { #1 } {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third~sentence. }             
    }
}

\seq_new:N \l__ghs_seq_numbers
\newcommand {\GHStext}[1]
{
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \HPsatz
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    Sentences (clist):

    \GHStext{H123, H125}
    
    Sentences (manual):

    \HPsatz{H123}
    \HPsatz{H125}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that makes my life much easier. I did not know about `\clist_map_function:nN`...

Comment: What if `\HPsatz` also takes two optional arguments that will be passed in the `clist`? Can you also easily use `\clist_map_function` then?

Comment: no if you have a two argument function you would need to construct a one-argument wrapper that does the mapping so to map a 2-agument \foo calling \foo{x}{...} for each element use `\clist_map_inline:Nn \clist_variable {\foo {x}{#1}}` @mrCarnivore

Answer (score 3):

You can even make everything fully expandable.

The guidelines suggest to separate the user interface with the internal implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\HPsatz}{m}
  {
    \ghs_satz:n { #1 } 
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GHStext}{m}
  {
    \ghs_text:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \ghs_satz:n
  {
    #1:~
    \str_case_e:nn { #1 } {
        { H123 }{ First~sentence. }
        { H124 }{ Second~sentence. }
        { H125 }{ Third~sentence. }             
    }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \ghs_text:n
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__ghs_text:n
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__ghs_text:n
  {
    \ghs_satz:n { #1 }~
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Sentences (clist):

\GHStext{H123, H125}
    
Sentences (manual):

\HPsatz{H123}
\HPsatz{H125}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for information: the loop you define with two counters can more simply be done with `\seq_map_inline:Nn` or `\seq_map_function:NN`.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I need some more time to fully understand your example and the advantages.

Comment: What is the `\ghs_text:n` for? Could you not just put the code into `\GHStext`? Why the extra 3 layers?

Comment: @mrCarnivore To distinguish between user interface and programming layer.

Comment: So you assume the content of the interface function also to be visible and therefore want to hide the real content also?

Comment: How do you create a `\cs_new:Nn` function that needs no arguments?

Comment: @mrCarnivore `\cs_new:Nn \prefix_name:`